# Chat app - updating last row

Tags: android, listview, chat

I am creating a chat app. As I get new chat from server I am updating the list by adding a last row to the list. But once I am sending a message I adds it to the list. When message is send I am getting success response from the server. I need to update the success message in the last row of the list without adding a new row.

I am pasting block of code from the adapter class

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (type == TYPE_MESSAGE) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_list_view, null);
        if(msg.equals("Seen")) {
        // need to change the status here. Dont add new row
        return view;
    }else if(msg.equals("Not Seen")) {
        // need to change the status here. Dont add new row

        return view;
    } else if(msg.equals("Received message")){
        // need to change the status here. Dont add new row     
        return view;
    } else {
        // else add new row and add new chat message
    }
    return view;
}
```

Can anybody give me a solution?

Thanks in advance.
Sundeep.S.

Answer (score 1):

update your existing message object who used in the list and notify the list adapter the dataset changed like this:

```
YourCrazyAdapter adapter = ((YourCrazyAdapter) listView.getAdapter());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no source provided, I can only try to guide you like

First pick the last item and set update its value. Then call `yourAdapter.setNotifyDatasetChanged()` and its done.

Comment: I need to update it from the adapter. Can I use setNotifyDatasetChanged() in side adapter?